# I want to extend the StringBuffer class in Android

Tags: java, android

However, before I even get started... -- literally, this is all the code I've written:

```
package com.my.package;

public class SBuffer extends StringBuffer
{

}
```

Eclipse is giving me this error:

```
The type SBuffer cannot subclass the final class StringBuffer.
```

So, StringBuffer is a FINAL class, and it seems I'm pretty well sunk before I start.  I thought I should ask the (much more knowledgeable than I) community for some suggestions on working around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want to extend it at the first place?

Comment: Currently, I want to add a method to easily replace the buffer contents -- there is a StringBuffer.replace() method, but it seems pretty clunky & inelegant to me.  Also, I'm pretty confident I'll find other things I'd like to implement over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a workaround would be to get the sourcecode (at least from standard JDK) from [here](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) and copy the code into your class and extend it

Comment: Now, THAT'S what I'm talking about.  I'm downloading now.

Comment: Stephen C's answer might be better, since StringBuilder class on itself will not work.You need to copy its supertype AbstractStringBuilder aswell. No need to download the full JDK, here are the classes: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.java.html and http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html

Comment: (whining.start()) Awesome timing...  (whining.actLikeAnAdult())   Yes, I did complete the download and unzip before you sent this, but I haven't actually started searching for the files.  So, you've saved me the really awful part.

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy `StringBuffer` **and** `AbstractStringBuilder`, change their respective packages, and modify `StringBuffer` to do what you want.

You can't simply copy / modify `StringBuffer` because it extends `AbstractStringBuilder` and the latter is package private.

---

Another approach might be to create a custom subclass of `Appendable` and `CharSequence`.  That gives you the option of leaving out `StringBuffer` functionality that you don't require and that might be harmful to performance in your particular use-case.

The fact that your class *cannot* be a subclass of the real `StringBuffer` class means that there is no longer any imperative to mimic to the `StringBuffer` API or conform to its behaviour.

Comment: Okay, this started out sounding fun and easy....  I'm just whining, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Rich - I did.  But the answer is the same in both the StringBuffer and StringBuilder cases.